# A suggestion for Spivak's book

Tags: soft-question, book-recommendation

I am starting to venture through the book "Calculus on Manifolds " by Michael Spivak . At the end of the first chapter , it mentions about a transformation matrix.  I haven't learned Linear Algebra ,so I was wondering if it would be fine to skip the understanding of this transformation matrix and continue to chapter 2. 
Waiting for suggestions .

Answer (score 2):

Ummm. Some things in mathematics build heavily on others. You need to know linear algebra before you can make any headway on differential geometry. Continue to chapter 2 and you are just going to find even more linear algebra throughout.

Linear algegra is key to much of multi-dimensional analysis and geometry. I strongly urge you to get a basic understanding of it before tackling those subjects.

Comment: How much would be sufficient to go through Spivak's book. Could you suggest some books or lecture notes ?

Comment: I learned it in pieces from a variety of sources of dubious quality, so I can't make any good recommendations. But you should know the basics of vector spaces, linear transformations, inner products, and how linear transformations are related to matrices. Also useful will be linear functionals and dual spaces. Tensors will be needed, but they may be hard to find outside of Diff. Geo. sources.